# Backbone Cleanup - removing references of context bound callbacks

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am working on a Backbone application. I created base view which has a destroy method and all other views extend it.

When destroying a view instance I want to make sure that if the view has a model or a collection I am unbinding any events it was listening to.

Assuming I am using underscores's _.bindAll in the view's initialize, will the off 
statement below remove the references.

```
var DocumentRow = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll( this );

     this.model.on('change', this.render);
  },


  destroy : function() {
      // Will this work?
      this.model.off(null, null, this);

  }


});
```

or do I need to explicitly bind events like so

```
this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
```

Comment: Why do you pass null into model.off?

Comment: To remove all the callbacks in the View. Based on the examples in the Backbone documentation : // Removes all callbacks for `context` for all events.
object.off(null, null, context);

Comment: Ok. I think this.model.on('change', this.render); should work fine, because render will be bound to 'this', your DocumentRow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.model.on('change', this.render);` will not work the way you want. You need to change it to `this.model.on('change', this.render, this);`

If you look at the source for the `on` method (http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-18 ) it does not default your `context` variable to anything. So if you don't set it, the call to `off` will not find the event bindings correctly.

FWIW, I get tired of having to do corresponding `on` and `off` calls, so I wrote a plugin to handle a lot of it for me: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.eventbinder

You can use it like this, and not have to worry about getting the right context or anything else.

```
var DocumentRow = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
     this.eb = new Backbone.EventBinder();
     this.eb.bindTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
  },


  destroy : function() {
      this.eb.unbindAll();
  }

});
```

The real benefit in this is not having to call `off` for every `on`. you only need to make one call to `unbindAll` and it will unbind all of the events that are stored in the event binder instance.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the eventBinder plugin